# Can't seem to get response from POST with NSURLConnection

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsurlconnection, nsurl, nsurlrequest

I have search around and can't quite find the right answer to this, but I have this code which posts data to my web server, and I am trying to get the HTTP response, but the response keeps returning (null). I can confirm that the connection is successful because the if statement (see below) executes the appropriate code.

Here is my code:

```
-(void)submitAction{
    NSString *post = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"&var1=%@&var2=%@&var3=%@&var4=%@",
                      _var1, _var2, _var3, _var4];
    NSData *postData = [post dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];
    NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",[postData length]];
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
    [request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://my-web-server.com/path-to-web-service/"]]];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
    [request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Current-Type"];
    [request setHTTPBody:postData];

    NSURLConnection *conn = [[NSURLConnection alloc]initWithRequest:request delegate:self];

    NSURLResponse *response;

    NSLog(@"%@", response); // Always returns null :(


    if(conn){
        NSLog(@"Connection Successful."); // Connection is successful in my tests.
    }else{
        NSLog(@"Connection could not be made");
    }
}
```

Here is the NSURLConnectionDelegate delegate implemented in my .h file:

```
@interface AddTaskViewController : UIViewController <UITextFieldDelegate, UIPickerViewDelegate, NSURLConnectionDelegate>
```

Can anyone see what I am doing wrong here? The server should return a JSON string, (and it does when I test the web service via my browser) but the NSURLResponse is constantly null.

Thanks,

Peter

Comment: You have to implement [NSURLConnectionDelegate](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSURLConnectionDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html) protocol. Read about delegation [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/general/conceptual/devpedia-cocoacore/Delegation.html).

Comment: I have this delegate already implemented in my .h file. Hold on and I'll update my code.

Comment: You can't implement anything in .h file. You implement delegates in .m file.

Comment: Again, read [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/general/conceptual/devpedia-cocoacore/Delegation.html) to understand what delegation is and how to use it.

Comment: How do I implement it in the .m file? How come UI delegates I can implement in the .h file?

Comment: No, you can't implement them in .h. That is a declaration, not implementation. Read the link i provided to understand how to do it.

Comment: See [this][1] post I just made for an example.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21970086/ios-parse-how-to-download-file-via-url/21970637#21970637

Comment: BTW, you post body has extra `&` at the start. Second, rather than using `dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES` you should be using `CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes` on the individual values as show at the end of [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21079176/1271826).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `initWithRequest:delegate:` of `NSURLConnection` starts an asynchronous download, so it returns immediately and executes straight away.

`response` is always `nil` because you just defined it and then logged it without ever setting it to anything. That needs to be done in the `connection:didReceiveResponse:` delegate method.

Where you do `if(conn){`, the `conn` existing doesn't mean the connection was successful, it just means that the connection could be created (basically, you didn't supply an invalid request). You don't know whether it's going to work yet.

Implement the delegate methods from [`NSURLConnectionDelegate_Protocol`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSURLConnectionDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html) (and [`NSURLConnectionDataDelegate`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSURLConnectionDataDelegate_protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/NSURLConnectionDataDelegate)) to get access to the response and downloaded data (when it becomes available).